# I want to increase swap space of my dual boot Ubuntu20.04 Os by 15gb

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, swap, hibernate

I read about this command on forums
sudo dd if = /dev/zero of= /swapfile bs=1G count=8.
but couldn't understant about this 'count' how much should i keep it. It would be kind if you provide complete code to safely increase the swap space. I want to hibernate my pc so want 20 gb of swap space...

Answer (score 1):

Disable current swap if you have one ...

```
sudo swapoff -v /swapfile
sudo rm /swapfile
```

If you have `fallocate` this creates a 20Gb swapfile

```
sudo fallocate -l 20G /swapfile
```

(Equivalent using `dd`:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1024 count=20971520
```

)

Set it to `600`...

```
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
```

and make into a swaparea ....

```
sudo mkswap /swapfile
```

after that add this line to `/etc/fstab` if it is not there yet:

```
/swapfile swap swap defaults 0 0
```

and then do

```
sudo swapon swapfile
```

to activate the new swap.

---

You can use `free` or `sudo swapon --show` to show the results.

Comment: I think you must include sudo swapon command also for complete, one more doubt please, when i changed fstab file, /swapfile none swap 0 0 was already there and i replaced it with the content given by you, did i did the right thing?? I am able to see 20gb of swap space now..

Comment: Yeah if is already there that is fine.

Comment: Also I am unable  to use this space for hybernation, how to debug it ;(